# How can I make DOT correctly process UTF-8 to PostScript and have multiple graph/pages?

Tags: utf-8, graphviz, postscript, dot

This dot source

```
graph A
{
    a;
}
graph B
{
    "Enûma Eliš";
}
```

when compiled with `dot -Tps` generates this error

> Warning: UTF-8 input uses non-Latin1 characters which cannot be handled by this PostScript driver

I can fix the UTF-8 problem by passing `-Tps:cairo` but then only graph A is in the output -- it is truncated to a single page. The same happens with `-Tpdf`. There are no other postscript driver available on my installation.

I could split the graphs into separate files and concatenate them afterwards, but I'd rather not. Is there a way to have correct UTF-8 handling and multiple page output?

Comment: You could try `blockdiag`, based on DOT syntax, but for block diagrams.  It's coded to properly handle UTF-8, but, not multiple diagrams in the same source.  Groups might do the trick though.  SVG output allows a separate image file per group.  `pip install blockdiag` to try it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the `dot` PS driver can't handle other encodings than the old ISO8859-1. I think it can't change fonts either.

One thing you can do is to run a filter to change `dot`'s PostScript output. The following Perl program does that, it's an adaptation of some code I had. It changes the encoding from UTF-8 to a modified ISO encoding with extra characters replacing unused ones.

Of course, the output still depends on the font having the characters. Since `dot` (I think) only uses the default PostScript fonts, anything beyond the "standard latin" is out of the question...

It works with Ghostscript or with any interpreter which defines `AdobeGlyphList`.

The filter should be used this way:

```
dot -Tps graph.dot | perl reenc.pl > output.ps
```

Here it is:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use open qw(:std :utf8);

my $ps = do { local $/; <STDIN> };
my %high;
my %in_use;
foreach my $char (split //, $ps) {
    my $code = (unpack("C", $char))[0];
    if ($code > 127) {
        $high{$char} = $code;
        if ($code < 256) {
            $in_use{$code} = 1;
        }
    }
}
my %repl;
my $i = 128;
foreach my $char (keys %high) {
    if ($in_use{$high{$char}}) {
        $ps =~ s/$char/sprintf("\\%03o", $high{$char})/ge;
        next;
    }
    while ($in_use{$i}) { $i++; }
    $repl{$i} = $high{$char};
    $ps =~ s/$char/sprintf("\\%03o", $i)/ge;
    $i++;
}
my $psprocs = <<"EOPS";
/EncReplacements <<
  @{[ join(" ", %repl) ]}
>> def
/RevList AdobeGlyphList length dict dup begin
  AdobeGlyphList { exch def } forall
end def
% code -- (uniXXXX)
/uniX { 16 6 string cvrs dup length 7 exch sub exch
  (uni0000) 7 string copy dup  4 2 roll putinterval } def
% font code -- glyphname
/unitoname { dup RevList exch known
  { RevList exch get }
  { uniX cvn } ifelse
  exch /CharStrings get 1 index known not
  { pop /.notdef } if
} def
/chg-enc { dup length array copy EncReplacements
  { currentdict exch unitoname 2 index 3 1 roll put } forall
} def
EOPS

$ps =~ s{/Encoding EncodingVector def}{/Encoding EncodingVector chg-enc def};
$ps =~ s/(%%BeginProlog)/$1\n$psprocs/;

print $ps;
```

Answer (score 4):

Generating PDF or SVG could bypass the encoding problem too.

```
dot  -Tpdf  chs.dot > chs.pdf

// or

dot  -Tsvg  chs.dot > chs.svg
```