# Font's poor quality in Graphviz

Tags: linux, fonts, graphviz, dot

I have extremely simple [DOT](http://www.graphviz.org/Documentation/dotguide.pdf) `test.gv` file:

```
digraph SampleGraph
{
  sampleNode [ label="StackOverflow" ];
}
```

When I render it with [`dot`](http://www.graphviz.org/pdf/dot.1.pdf) with `-Tpdf` flag, I have really poor quality pixelated font.

This is result of `dot test.gv -Tpdf > test.pdf`:
[image: DOT to PDF image]

[PostScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostScript) flag `-Tps` works fine. This is result of `dot test.gv -Tps > test.ps`:
[image: DOT to PS image]

Why?

---

*Edit:* I've found [Graphviz font FAQ](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/fontfaq.txt) but it doesn't explain this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even the official [documentation](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/output.html#d:pdf) doesn't recommend to use direct `-Tpdf` conversion.

> pdf
>
> Produces PDF output. (This option assumes Graphviz includes the Cairo renderer.) Alternatively, one can use the ps2 option to
>   produce PDF-compatible PostScript, and then use a ps-to-pdf converter.
>   Note: At present, this option does not support anchors, etc. To get these 
>   included in your PDF output, use ps2.

It doesn't support several things, they marked it with etc. So you can guess what else they don't support with `-Tpdf`.

Better convert it to `ps` then to pdf with `ps2pdf` from ghostscript package.

`ps2pdf myfile.ps myfile.pdf`

---

Also have a look at this

> No freetype.  ============
>
> When graphviz is built on systems without freetype, then only the gd
>   renderer will be available for bitmap outputs, and the only available
>   fonts are a small set of builtin bitmap fonts.  The poor quality of
>   these fonts will be evident, also, "dot ... -v 2>&1 | grep font"  will
>   say that the font is "". This may actually be desirable for
>   installing minimal graphviz programs on a server where fonts may not
>   even be installed.

Probably you need to install freetype fonts and rebuild `dot` if you have built it manually

Comment: Great! Thanks, it almost works. **Almost** because in fact I use *UTF8* (polish) characters in my label and `dot test.gv -Tps2 > test.ps` produces the following message: `Warning: UTF-8 input uses non-Latin1 characters which cannot be handled by this PostScript driver`.

Comment: Check out following thread for the issue with UTF-8 characters http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27732134/how-can-i-make-dot-correctly-process-utf-8-to-postscript-and-have-multiple-graph